# Use VBA with Regression add-in

Tags: vba, excel, regression

I downloaded this multivariate regression add-in from this website:
http://www3.wabash.edu/econometrics/EconometricsBook/Basic%20Tools/ExcelAddIns/OLSRegression.htm

The following code attempts to run the add-in. However, after I have set my ranges as arrays, the code is still saying an array is expected.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub XLAExample()
    Dim x
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim xy As Double
    Dim xyz As Double

    xy = ws.Range("b2:b3750")
    xyz = ws.Range("bm2:bm3750")

   x = OLSRegressionAddIn.MatrixWorkNew(xy, xyz)




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parentheses during

```
Dim xy() As Double
Dim xyz() As Double
```

lines. You need them to declare an array

Edit: Example below of how to dim and then set array

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as WorkSheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim testArr() As Variant
testArr = ws.Range("A1:A5") 'obviously replace with correct range
```

Comment: When I try to set a range to the array, it says type mismatch.    `Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("BK1:BK3750")`
  `xvals() = rng`

Comment: @Daruki when you are setting the array equal, you don't use the parentheses. I added an example above

Comment: @Daruki Also just for future reference, you may want to read [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)